# Proguard with Scala - Error 4

Tags: scala, proguard

Proguard 5.1 fails during the shrinking phase with "Error: 4".
The proguard configuration file is as follows:

```
-injars      ReversiRaw.jar
-outjars     Reversi.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar

-dontwarn scala.**

-dontnote
-dontwarn
-ignorewarnings

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    ** MODULE$;
}
```

Which is mostly the default Scala configuration given in the documentation.
A download link to the jar file being compreseed for reproducing: [download](http://www11.zippyshare.com/v/79090628/file.html)

What is that "Error: 4", and how can it be fixed or avoided?

Comment: I hit this issue as well.  I am new to Proguard

Answer (score 1):

The other solution might be using gradle.

This is the gradle source to build, get the fat file (shadowJar file), and shrink the jar file with proguard.

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        flatDir dirs: '/Users/smcho/Dropbox/smcho/bin/jar/proguard5.2/lib'
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':proguard'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

shadowJar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'HelloWorld'
  }
}

dependencies{
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.5"
}

task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
//    injars './build/classes'
    injars './build/libs/scala_all_jar-all.jar'
    outjars './build/libs/main.jar'
    libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"

    dontwarn
    dontnote
    ignorewarnings

    keepattributes 'SourceFile,LineNumberTable'

    keepclasseswithmembers 'public class * { \
        public static void main(java.lang.String[]); \
    }'
}
```

You need to set `flatDir dirs` to point to where your proguard files are located.

`gradle build` will get you the compiled classes and jar file, `gradle shadowJar` will get you big jar file, and `gradle proguard` will give you the slimmed jar file named `main.jar`.

I also uploaded the source: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10773282/share/2015/scala_all_jar.zip

Answer (score 1):

While prosseek's answers was helpful, I was able to get a simple Hello-World proguard configuration working without having to resort to class files. (Unlike prosseek, I didn't try an Uberjar, though).

Adapting from [the Scala example in the Proguard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#scala), I got a simple `*.pro` would look something like:

```
-injars      build/install/HelloScala/lib/helloscala-1.0.jar
-injars      build/install/HelloScala/lib/scala-library-2.11.6.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
-outjars     helloscalapro.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar

-dontwarn scala.**

//etc.
```

Filtering out the manifest from the Scala library.

I also got Error 4 when the version of the Scala library I passed to `injar` was a different (patch) version than the Scala version I'd compiled it with.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue when my injar jar file is a fat jar from plugins assembly through `sbt assembly` command. 
The solution to this problem is not to use the fat jar, but to use the classes generated from scala, and other java/scala libraries to get slimmed jar file.

On my mac (OS X 10.10), I have this proguard file (named your.pro).

```
-injar classes
-injar /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.5/libexec/lib/scala-library.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
-outjar main.jar
-libraryjar /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Classes/classes.jar

-dontwarn
-dontnote
-ignorewarnings

-optimizationpasses 2
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable

-keep,allowoptimization,allowshrinking class * { *; }
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }
```

This is the directory structure.

```
.
├── classes
│   ├── HelloWorld$.class
│   ├── HelloWorld$delayedInit$body.class
│   ├── HelloWorld.class
│   └── META-INF
│       └── MANIFEST.MF
├── src
│   └── hello.scala
└── your.pro
```

hello.scala is as follows:

```
object HelloWorld extends App 
{
    println("Hello, world")
}
```

You can get the class files in the classes directory with `scalac src/hello.scala -d classes`. The MANIFEST file should be added to tell which is the main class. Careful with the last blank line.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: HelloWorld
... blank line should be here ...
```

The classes file is generated from scala.
With `proguard @your.pro`, I could get working jar file.

I uploaded the example in https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10773282/share/2015/scala_class.zip